# why does my white noise have beating/popping/bleating?

Tags: android, audio

My android app is trying to generate white noise to play on an android device. Currently, I'm generating an array of random numbers that is AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(...) shorts long, and looping through in a timer. It looks like this:

```
    INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS = (int)((double)(bufSize) / (double)(nativeSampleRate * 2) * 1000);

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            synchronized(this){
                //System.out.println("playing. Sample rate is + " + nativeSampleRate + ", buffer is " + data.length + " shorts long, interval is " + INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS);
                track.write(data, 0, bufSize);
                track.play();
            }
        }

    }, 0, INTERVAL_MILLISECONDS);
```

But when I listen to it on my android emulator, I get white noise with a very rapid "beating" or "bleating" rhythm that's hard to describe. I'm not a sound engineer, can someone point me in the right direction about why this is happening?

********************** UPDATE ************************
I just did a couple of variations, one where I made sure my sample size was a whole number of milliseconds long, and one where I made my sample size a whole second long.

With a sample size of 8820 (five milliseconds long, and still over the 8192 minimum), the beating is unchanged.

However, with a sample size of 44100 (a whole second), the beating went away. Is it possible the timer I'm using just isn't accurate at the small intervals?

Comment: Is the rate of the beating the same every time you run it?

Comment: Hehehe, completely unrelated, but maybe SlenderMan is trying to take you away...! Be afeared. Be very afeared....

Comment: Erik, that's a good question, I think it might be. My sample rate is 44100 and my buffer size is 8192, meaning the pattern repeats 5.38 times per second (sample length is about 185 milliseconds long), and the bleating/beating sounds like it might be about that fast. Any thoughts on how to smooth it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the way you're generating white noise. I don't know the first thing about programming on the android, but if I understand the question correctly you're creating a single buffer's worth of random data then cycling through it over and over again.

The problem, (as your update points out) is that this single buffer is repeating several times a second. This means it's no longer 'white' (i.e. completely random) noise. It's become periodic.

Your brain is very good at picking out periodic waveforms, hence why you hear this beating. It's your brain telling you that there's something going on other than the white noise. Here you're introducing a strong component around 5.38Hz, which when modulating the rest of the audio you interpret as a "beating" effect.

The beating disappears (or decreases below perceptibility) when you increase the buffer length because at 44100 samples your brain no longer has enough to latch on to, and hence fails to recognise that the sequence is periodic. The low frequency information will still be there though.

Generating perfect white noise [isn't as straightforward as you might think!](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-generate-white-gaussian-noise). In your case I think it's best to make the noise buffer as long as possible - depending of course on the context of the application you're building.

Comment: couldn't you generate multiple buffers and repeat them in random orders to reduce the brain's perception of beats/patterns?

Comment: @Jon - Cool idea. I guess ultimately it's a compromise between hardware demand and how pure you need the white noise to be.

Comment: Excellent! That did it! Thank you, @Speedy! @Jon, your multiple buffer idea is going to save me a lot of CPU cycles on the mobile device. Know what's interesting? I can still hear the beating when I choose my 5millisecond sample randomly among 15 randomly generated buffers, though it's quiet. But when I go to 20 buffers, the artifact goes away.

Comment: @Daniel Really interesting! Here's a thought, why not have a function to generate high quality noise as and when you require it? There'd be a small performance cost which might be offset by saving on memory/table access times. I guess it depends which is under more demand in your case; #CPU cycles or memory.

Comment: @Speedy, yeah, I thought about that. I haven't experimented with it since I now have a solution that's working, but it's always been my experience that random number generation is very CPU intensive and 20 sets of 8192 16-bit-shorts is only 320k of memory, which doesn't seem that abusive, even on a mobile device.